# How to assign multiple strings to one key in dictionary ?

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I am working on script which is going to run loop over a input file and extract and/or change some words in the text file. Depending on parameter from console values of all variables from nested loops will be modified accordingly.

My question is: what would be the best way of storing values of variables for all valid parameters? I was considering using dictionary, however I am unsure if I will be able to store more than one string per one key? Essentially I would like to be able to retrieve set of strings and assign their values to the set of variables - based on key value. Some sort of 'nested' dictionary, equivalent of two dimensional array in Java.

Please help me find a suitable (the best and fastest) solution.

Thank you.

Comment: We need to see some of the code you have tried. If you are unsure if a dictionary will work, have you read the Python documentation on the dictionary type? Have you tried to code what you think will work? Did you get an error, a backtrace, showing where you have gone wrong?

Comment: @nemo Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will find this a very helpful place to get answers to you programming questions *when* you post code and results showing specifically what is going wrong. Questions without code are harder to answer, and are often closed.

Comment: Python doesn't really care about types, so you can store strings and string lists in the same dict. You can use a check to see if something is a string or a list before working with it. Better to just store a list of 1 string in the first place, though. Also see defaultdict so that you can initialize your created dict elements to [] (empty lists) automatically.

Comment: @William Denman, Eric Wilson - thank you, I appreciate you suggestion but my intention was to find out what would be acceptable way of doing it. Now based on below suggestion I am going to implement that and probably ask more questions which will include some code. Thank you.

Comment: Even though you got an answer, that's not the spirt of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one could help

**Use tuple** or **list** for the multiple string

I recommend use tuple, because I assume that the sentences will never change.

```
my_dict = {
    1:("Hello", "World"),
    2:("Stackoverflow", "is", "Great")
}
```

Comment: I like this idea. I will try to implement that. I wonder if there is any 'faster' solution? Forgive me if this is silly question but my experience with Python is very little. Thank you

Comment: @nemo, perhaps you need more time with Python first before you worry about performance. Simple is better when you are learning something new. Unless you have a huge data right now then you can worry about the faster solution, otherwise that would be a [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to store the file in json format.

In order to meet the requirement of retrieving and assignment in a fast way, (k, v) and (v, k) should be store in the json value,eg.something like inverted-table. Code example,

json format(DataStructure):

> {k1:[v1,v2], k2:[v1], v1:[k1,k2], v2:[k1]}

Two operations can be made in O(1) time.